# Exception in Host Object::get: <unknown>

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications

I am trying to use firebase notification to my project. I have followed the instruction on its site. When I run the app, I get this:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhSI.png)

I have read [this link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1998). Adding database and auth depth not working for me.